# Elevatezoom click not working on ios. cursor:pointer?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios

I´m using the elevatezoom plugin for my website. (the gallery-lightbox)

http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/image-zoom/examples#gallery-lightbox

It works on every device except on my iphone. 
 The zoom works fine, but as soon as i click on the picture, no fancybox opens.

I think, ios somehow has a problem with this code.

```
("#zoom_03").bind("click", function(e) { 
var ez = $('#zoom_03').data('elevateZoom'); 
$.fancybox(ez.getGalleryList()); 
return false; 
});
```

is there a way to get it working?

I read:
Just add: `cursor: pointer` to your  link a problem solved!

and i read:

try 
`$(document).on("click touchstart", "#id", function(event) {...`

I tried all of that, but it don´t work.

Please help me with this. :)

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I'm facing the exact same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Hide zoomContainer through css and this will work. It worked for me.